# Swap two numbers in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone explain to me why this `swap` method doesn't swap two numbers?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] arr) {
    int original1 = 5;
    int original2 = 10;
    swap(original1, original2);
    System.out.println(original1);
    System.out.println(original2);
}

static void swap(int a, int b){
    int temp = a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}}
```

Comment: because you swap them in different scopes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Essentially, the two ints are copied and in the swap method you swap the copied variables, not the original ones.

Comment: tl;dr: since java has pass-by-value semantics, you cannot do what you want to do with primitives. You can do this, however, with arrays.

Comment: The above code is following the calling convention of "Call By Value". So basically you are passing values, not references. Hence its not changed.